# Getting the frame duration of an animated GIF?

Tags: c#, .net, animated-gif

In C#, I can get the individual frames from a gif and show the animation easily enough, but how do you go about getting the timing information for each frame?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
PropertyItem item = img.GetPropertyItem (0x5100); // FrameDelay in libgdiplus
// Time is in milliseconds
delay = (item.Value [0] + item.Value [1] * 256) * 10;
```

[This](http://web.archive.org/web/20130820015012/http://madskristensen.net/post/Examine-animated-Gife28099s-in-C.aspx) article may be useful.

Comment: To clarify: The GIF stores the interval in s/100. The variable `delay` contains the interval in milliseconds.